# How do I echo out something different when reached last row?

Tags: php, mysql

I am wanting to not echo out the comma at the end of the echo after the last row. How can I do that? Here is my code:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo '{"points":[';

    mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
    mysql_select_db("database");

    $q = "SELECT venues.id, venues.lat, venues.lon, heat_indexes.temperature FROM venues, heat_indexes WHERE venues.id = heat_indexes.venue_id";

    $res = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($point = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $point['lat'] . "," . $point['lon'] . "," . $point['temperature'] . ",";
    }
    mysql_free_result($res);
    echo ']}';
    ?>
```

Comment: If anyone has a more effective way to return this data, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) instead, rather than hand-crafting the JSON?

```
$result = array();

//snip

while ($point = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $result[] = $point['lat'];
    $result[] = $point['lon'];
    $result[] = $point['temperature'];
}

//snip

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode( array('points' => $result) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a count query to get the number of rows to begin with.

```
$query= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM venues";
$count= mysql_query($q);
```

Then introduce a conditional and a count decrease each time through...

```
while ($point = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $count = $count - 1;
    if ($count == 1) {
        echo $point['lat'] . "," . $point['lon'] . "," . $point['temperature'];
    } else {
    echo $point['lat'] . "," . $point['lon'] . "," . $point['temperature'] . ",";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Json encode would probably be your best bet, but you could also use trim();

Rather than echoing in the while loop, append to a variable. Once outside the while loop, use $output = trim($output, ',') to remove trailing commas.

Comment: That is what I am going to use. Json_encode is working fine now and is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

About the comma problem, I always target the first item instead of the last:

```
$first = true;
while ($point = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    if ($first)
    {
        $first = false;
    }
    else
    {
        echo ",";
    }
    echo $point['lat'] . "," . $point['lon'] . "," . $point['temperature'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql_num_rows()` to find out how many rows are in the result set passed back from your last query.

```
...
$res = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($res);
```

Then combine that with Scotts answer and you should be set.